# MySQL creating a common table for common fields of many tables

Tags: mysql, sql, database-design

I have 100+ MYSQL tables in my project and most of the project have common fields like created_by, last_modified_date, last_modified_by and few other fields. Is this good idea to make a new table with these common fields and add one to one relationship with this table. Eg.

- common_table: id, created_by, last_modified_by
- table1: id, name, address, **common_table_id**
- table2: id, name, balance, date, **common_table_id**
- table3: id, price, isActive, **common_table_id**
- tableN: fields ...., **common_table_id**

In the above example I have a table name **common_table** with all the common fields and this table has one to one relationship with all the other tables. This has made me easier to add or update the common fields easier without having it replicate in all the tables. Since I am in development phase, does this method has performance drawback or will it cause other production issues in the future?

Comment: This won't work if the same ID can be in different tableN.

Comment: Each table will have their own common table id i.e. the common table is not reusable.

Comment: There's little benefit to doing this, IMHO.

Comment: Splitting a table should represent a logical relationship between entities. You don't do it just because the columns are similar. It doesn't save storage space (all the same data has to be stored, they're just in different tables), and it makes queries more complicated.

Comment: Yes I agree, now I am dropping this idea to share a common table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In terms of querying, I would not expect any problems -- assuming that `common_table_id` has a primary keys.  There might be some issues if you have very large tables and small tabes.  The common table might end up being loaded into memory, even when only small pieces are being used (because the referring tables are small).

A bigger concern might be updates, where inserts/updates on different tables now have common columns that are also being modified.  This can introduce locking dependencies.  However, if inserts are relatively infrequent (no more than a handful per second), this probably isn't an issue.

You might want to tweak the model to have a table id in the common table as well.  You can use this for partitioning the table.  That way, only the common elements for a given table need to be loaded into memory for queries and updates.

Answer (score 0):

- 1-to-1 is a red flag.
- Redundant data is a red flag.

If `table1` and `table2` are 1:1, there is rarely a valid reason to split them into two tables.  Even if this leads to having 100 columns in the single table.

Present a *small* set of data.  Be sure to include any variations -- right know I cannot tell whether `balance` and `price` share the *same* create_date, or that each has its own create_date, and they may be different.